# How do I store an array of objects with nested objects as attributes using react hook's useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am fetching an array of Expense objects that contains 2 objects with as attributes that contain their own set of objects as attributes. This is what it looks like:

```
{
"expenses": [
    {
        "id": "5b996064dfd5b783915112f5",
        "amount": {
            "value": "1854.99",
            "currency": "EUR"
        },
        "date": "2018-09-10T02:11:29.184Z",
        "merchant": "Burger King",
        "receipts": [],
        "comment": "",
        "category": "",
        "user": {
            "first": "Vic",
            "last": "Rob",
            "email": "Vic@rob.com"
        },
        "index": 0
    },
    {
        "id": "5b99606474ab17b7820b3922",
        "amount": {
            "value": "3222.88",
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "date": "2018-08-13T07:11:01.680Z",
        "merchant": "McD",
        "receipts": [],
        "comment": "",
        "category": "",
        "user": {
            "first": "craig",
            "last": "Michael",
            "email": "craig@craig.com"
        },
        "index": 1
    },
]
```

Now I want to iterate through the response array and add them my hook's data variable and have attempted to do accordingly:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState({expenses:[]});
 const Realm = require("realm");
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  const result = await axios(
   'http://localhost:3000/expenses?limit=10&offset=0',
  );
  writeData(result.data)
};
fetchData();
}, []);

const writeData = data =>{
Realm.open({
schema: [ExpenseSchema, UserSchema, AmountSchema]
}).then(realm => {
realm.write(() => {
  data.expenses.map((expense) => {
    realm.create ('expense',expense)
   setData ([...data, expense]);  //returns an error. same if i use Object.values(expense)
   console.log (expense)
    });
});
});
}
```

and lastly, here is what my schema looks like:

```
const AmountSchema = {
 name: "amount",
properties: {
value: "string",
currency: "string"
}
};

    const UserSchema = {
  name: "user",
  properties: {
    first: "string",
    last: "string",
    email: "string"
  }
};
const ExpenseSchema = {
  name: "expense",
  primaryKey: "id",
  properties: {
    id: "string",
    amount: "amount?",
    user: "user?",
    date: "date",
    merchant: "string",
    receipt: "data?"
  }
};
```

When I run this, I get the following error: *Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance*

How do I get around this?

**EDIT:**  I know one options is the access the object attributes and store them in a stringified form, but I'd prefer not to hack my way around this. I was suggested to use useReducer but I am new to Hooks and havn't yet figured out how a reducer would solve this. If this is the way, an example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregard my previous response, this is because you're storing an *object* in your `data` variable, but you are treating it as an *array* when you try to spread it.

I'd recommend storing the expenses array in its own separate piece of state, seeing as you currently have no other data there.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Should fix your problem. And then replace `data.expenses.map` with `data.map` and `writeData(result.data)` with `writeData(result.data.expenses)`.

All together:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const Realm = require("realm");
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
        'http://localhost:3000/expenses?limit=10&offset=0',
    );
    writeData(result.data.expenses)
  };
  fetchData();
}, []);

const writeData = data =>{
  Realm.open({
    schema: [ExpenseSchema, UserSchema, AmountSchema]
  }).then(realm => {
    realm.write(() => {
      data.map((expense) => {
        realm.create ('expense',expense)
        setData ([...data, expense]);  //returns an error. same if i use Object.values(expense)
        console.log (expense)
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sir @Rutherford Wonkington. I have two questions: 1) Can you please explain how I was treating it as an array as opposed to an object? 2) How is the solution storing the expenses array in its own separate piece of state as opposed to how it was being done before?

Comment: ```setData ([...data, expense])``` is destructuring ```data``` as though it were an array, but data is equal to ```{expenses:[]}``` which is an object with one property that's set equal to an empty array, but is not an array itself.  By converting ```data``` to an array, you're removing the type mismatch, rather than using an object with an unnecessary ```expenses``` prop.  There's no need to keep an object with only a single key--you can just store that value directly.